# 'Read more' affecting more than one box - how to change it? (jQuery/JS/CSS)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-ui

so I want to implement **'Read more'** on my friend site.

I achieve effect that I wanted but when I started changing the box alignment the **'Read more'** effect got hit.

Before: https://codepen.io/szlvga/pen/poNOqpO

After: https://codepen.io/szlvga/details/yLVQQoY

I want it to affect only the box that I'm click **'Read more'** button like on the first Codepen and not all the boxes in the row like on the second Codepen.

How to achieve that? Thanks in advance.

```
Everything is on codepen.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jQuery code is correct, the problem is your layouting and more specifically flexbox. Your `.row` class has `align-items: stretch`, so when one item expands, all others in the same row will expand to fill the stretched space.

This snippet will fix your problem:

```
.row {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: flex-start; /* < Align items to top, don't stretch them! */
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

You can read more on flexbox and the `align-items` property [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: At first I thought it worked but now I have other problem... Overall thanks but will reply again when I'll put the site on hosting. Thanks anyway!

Comment: So @Georgi if you have a minute; I published my website for test on some free hosting 

[link](http://robertdesign.myartsonline.com/strona-glowna/) 

I used Wordpress and Oxygen Builder to make it. 

As you can see only one box is affected when I click 'Read more' which is good but in a iPad Pro mode the boxes are not the same height. What do you recommend? 
Thanks in advance... 
That's the only one problem I have before optimizing the page and publishing it.

Comment: I see you are still using `align-items: stretch`?

Comment: I dunno @Georgi ... Even if I change everything to flex-start it keep shrinking not evenly on iPad mode. Changed stretch to flex-start with F12 when on site and it didn't help. Weird. It isn't so important but I would like it fixed, maybe next time.. Thanks anyway. 

What I found is that when I uncheck `*, ::after, ::before {
    /* box-sizing: inherit;` then boxes are same size but wrong position, I think I should ask on Oxygen group about this.